# Lognormal asymmetry implication on Value at Risk

Tags: monte-carlo, value-at-risk, log-returns

To examine the Value at Risk implications for a portfolio consisting of a spot and futures time series I have generated a 1-day monte carlo simulation. I was long in the spot and short in the future (the amount was determined by the minimum variance hedge ratio). Now my question is since I am calculating the Value at Risk at the price level and these are lognormally distributed will the Value at Risk of my portfolio change depending on if I'm long or short in spot (the fraction of the futures stays the same). My guess would be that it indeed should not be the same due to the asymmetry of the distribution, but I hope someone could help elaborate on that a little more